# Can a Spring 4 application support spring-beans.dtd when it is run in a firewalled enviorment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

I have a Spring 4 project that when it is deployed it is run behind a very restrictive firewall. The effect of this firewall is that my project cannot download anything from the internet when it is starting up/running. My project has a dependency on a library jar that contains spring configuration files that use spring-beans.dtd. The Spring 3 jars came packaged with spring-beans.dtd, however the Spring 4 jars do not. When spring attempts to initialize the beans it will try to download spring-beans.dtd, this fails because it is blocked by the firewall and results in a stack trace.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [jar:file:/<someFile>]; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:242)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 59 more
```

I know that the problematic configuration files should be updated from spring beans.dtd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>

</beans>
```

to spring-beasns.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

however, I do not have access to change them.

Is there some way to package up the spring-beans.dtd file similarly to how it was done in Spring 3 so that when the beans are initialized it will use the local version instead of trying to download one?

Comment: Why not move to java config? Then you can throw all those painful xml files away and not have this problem. Alternatively, just delete the doctype entry from your config files.

Comment: btw: spring shouldn't have a problem running in a firewalled environment, as this is it's usual home. You should not have any failure because it's trying to fetch a dtd.

Comment: @EngineerDollery The config file is located in a dependency jar that I do not have access too.

Comment: @EngineerDollery It does fail in a firewalled environment. In older version of spring this was not a problem because they included spring-beans.dtd, spring 4 does not.

Comment: I've been using spring4, in a heavily secure environment (maybe the most secure, who knows), since its release, and this has never been an issue, not even once. However, I don't know what's going on in your code, so I won't presume that your stuff is the same as my stuff. Have you tried serving the dtd from a webserver on the same box you're deploying to, and redirecting the request either through a proxy or by adding an entry to the hosts file?

Comment: Also, have you seen this? https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5014

Comment: I had same problem when I was migrating my application from spring 3 to spring 4. actually this problem is raised when your application run or deploying without internet. please, read jira issue of spring. [https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12836]

Comment: @Raju189 I get an error when attempting to follow that link. "The issue you are trying to view does not exist."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I had was that I was importing a bean definition file that used *.dtd xml validation into a spring 4 project. Since I did not have access to make changes to the dependency jar, I opted to copy the bean definitions out of the problematical spring files into the local spring files for my  project.

**Before:**

*Problematic bean definition file located in dependency jar*

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
  <bean id="dependendBean" class="someClass" />
</beans>
```

*Local bean definitions*

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <import resource="classpath*:/dependency-beans.xml"/>

</beans>
```

**After:**

*Local bean definitions*

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="dependendBean" class="someClass" />

</beans>
```